# What type of co-sleeping product hangs off the side of the bed?

Tags: cosleeping

We're on our third child.  The first two would nurse and then go right to sleep in the bassinet.  This one seems to sleep well in the bed, but not in the bassinet.  My wife looked online and found these co-sleeping things that help prevent bad things from happening: rolling on top of them, suffocating on blankets, etc.

I asked our doctor and she said she's comfortable with the "side" co-sleepers, but not the ones that lay in the middle of the bed.  It sounded like the doctor described something that hangs off the side of the bed.  When searching Amazon, though, I can only find full-size bassinets that pull up to the bed or co-sleepers that just lay on the mattress - nothing that hangs off the side.  We're probably not interested in buying a whole new bassinet at $150.

Do you think the doc was just mixed up?  Have you used one of these products?  Do you feel safe with them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

http://www.thisnext.com/tag/bassinets/

[image]

From what I've understood it's not on the market presently?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to a UK charity NCT (National Childbirth Trust) online shop which sells a few products like you describe.

http://www.nctshop.co.uk/Sleeping/products/27/?gclid=CLa63fyD9qoCFYELfAodekOwLQ

[image: bedside cot]

Here's an Amazon.co.uk link for a product which is not a full size cot:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/NScessity-100101-BabyBay-Co-Sleeping-Cot/dp/B000OKQ8DO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1314673713&sr=8-1

This product is expensive!  It's over £200; that's about $320us or €220euro.

Answer (score 1):

We used an ordinary wooden cot with one side taken off, and put that by the side of the bed, with a scrunched-up duvet to plug the gap in-between.  It's better value than buying a special item, but only if you happen to have a cot already!

Answer (score 1):

There is something called a co-sleeper  and I bought this one by "Arms Reach"  http://amzn.com/B00198F1X8

It basically sits on the side of the bed and there are some straps that wrap around under your mattress to keep it in place and snug against the bed. It also converts into a little play pen for later use.  This is the one that I saw recommended the most when doing my research.